How can I use Font Awesome icons in a web project?
I tried using <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i> to insert the github icon into my work but it didn't show. How do I achieve this? Please I need help as soon as possible so that I can finish and submit an assignment I was given. Thanks.

You have two options:

The way Font Awesome wants you to do it is create a unique kit on their website, and then they’ll give you the code to include the kit in your project.

A simpler way is simply to reference Cloudflare’s CDN distribution of it, as per this answer.


